# Deleting an index doesn't delete the data getting mapper_parsing_exception?

Tags: elasticsearch

If I want to restart everything? How do I do that?
I currently developing a search and I want to reset. 
The problem is that I delete the index and it returns:
200 OK `{"acknowledged":true}`

So I update the mapping I get:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [person]: mapper [country] cannot be changed from type [string] to [int]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [person]: mapper [country] cannot be changed from type [string] to [int]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [country] cannot be changed from type [string] to [int]"}},"status":400}
```

The problem is that I create another index with another name and I get the same problem:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [person]: mapper [country] cannot be changed from type [string] to [int]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [person]: mapper [country] cannot be changed from type [string] to [int]","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"mapper [country] cannot be changed from type [string] to [int]"}},"status":400}
```

I create it using:

```
{
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1,
        "analysis": { 
            "analyzer": {
                "sortable": {
                    "type": "custom",
                    "tokenizer": "keyword",
                    "filter": [
                        "lowercase"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "mappings" : {
// Left out on purpose.
    }
}
```

I really don't care about the data I just want the quickest way create a new index. Is the mappings stored in a different place than the index? I thought that if you delete the index the types + data disappears.

Comment: I have updated my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you dropped index you did not stopped indexing. By default elasticsearch will create index and mapping for you. You can [disable autocreation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html#index-creation). Or you can make sure that indexing is stopped

Comment: Yeah that seems to be the case because I got this in the logs: [2016-06-21 11:14:23,502][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [Frenzy] [index_5000] creating index, cause [auto(delete api)], templates [], shards [5]/[1], mappings []

Comment: Can I disable auto_create_index without going to the config files. I would prefer to just use the API?

Comment: In api you can only disable index.mapper.dynamic, but for auto_create_index  you must update config on all nodes. this is from documentation